# match index notation of file1 to the index of file2 and pull out matching rows

Tags: shell, awk, sed

file1 contains multiple alphabetic sequences:

```
AETYUIOOILAKSJ
EAYEURIOPOSIDK
RYXURIAJSKDMAO
URITORIEJAHSJD
YWQIAKSJDHFKCM
HAJSUDIDSJSIAJ
AJDHDPFDIXSIBJ
JAQIAUXCNCVUFO
```

while file2 contains indexes of the sequences which I want to pull out and transfer to another file. For example, 3T means I want the sequence with a T at position 3 from within file1.
In reality both files are very large with thousands of indexes and sequences.
file2:

```
3T
10K
14D
1J
```

Desired output:

```
AETYUIOOILAKSJ
RYXURIAJSKDMAO
URITORIEJAHSJD
JAQIAUXCNCVUFO
```

Ideally the output should match the order of indexes in file2. In other words the first index "3T" matches sequence "AETYUIOOILAKSJ" and thus this is the first sequence in the new file.

Things I have tried:

```
grep -f file2 file1
grep -fov file2 file1 # possibly to filter for those non-matching entries
```

I have also used the command line tool sift but am still having difficulty.
Thanks

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236). The attempts you present, clearly cannot work as they do not closely represent the logic you describe. For one, where is the counting.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR {
    lgth = length($0)
    pos2char[substr($0,1,lgth-1)] = substr($0,lgth,1)
    next
}
{
    for (pos in pos2char) {
        if ( substr($0,pos,1) == pos2char[pos] ) {
            print
            next
        }
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file2 file1
AETYUIOOILAKSJ
RYXURIAJSKDMAO
URITORIEJAHSJD
JAQIAUXCNCVUFO
```

Answer (score 1):

With `awk` + `grep` pipeline:

```
awk '{ pat=sprintf("%*s", int($0)-1, ""); gsub(" ", ".", pat); 
       printf "^%s%s\n", pat, substr($0, length) }' file2 | grep -f- file1
```

The output:

```
AETYUIOOILAKSJ
RYXURIAJSKDMAO
URITORIEJAHSJD
JAQIAUXCNCVUFO
```

Comment: I have noticed that this works for short sequences, however, when file1 contains unique sequences extending to say 200 characters, the resulting output is greater than the index file (file2).

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {b[$0]++;next} {for (i in b) {a=match($0,"[A-Z]");n=substr($0,1,(a-1));s=substr($0,a);t=substr(i,n,1);if (t==s) print i}}' file1 file2
AETYUIOOILAKSJ
RYXURIAJSKDMAO
URITORIEJAHSJD
JAQIAUXCNCVUFO
```

Some more readable:

```
awk '
NR==FNR {
  b[$0]++;
  next
} 
{
  for (i in b) {
    a=match($0,"[A-Z]");
    n=substr($0,1,(a-1));
    s=substr($0,a);
    t=substr(i,n,1);
    if (t==s) 
      print i
    }
}
' file1 file2
```

With comments:

```
awk '
NR==FNR {                 # For the first file
  b[$0]++;                # Store file1 in in array b
  next
} 
{
  for (i in b) {          # Loop trough elements in array b
    a=match($0,"[A-Z]");  # For file2 find where letters starts
    n=substr($0,1,(a-1)); # Store the number part of file2 in n
    s=substr($0,a);       # Store the letters part of file2 in s
    t=substr(i,n,1);      # from file1 find string at position n
    if (t==s)             # test if string found is equal to letter to find s
      print i             # if yes, print the line 
    }
}
' file1 file2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '(NR==FNR){a[$0]=substr($0,length);next}
     { for(key in a) if (a[key] == substr($0,key+0,1)) { print; break }
     }' file2 file1
```

Here, the array `a[key]` is a associative array with the following key-value pairs:

```
key:   value
3T     T
10K    K
...    ...
```

When processing `file2` with the line: `(NR==FNR){a[$0]=substr($0,length);next}`: we extract the `value` beforehand so we don't have to do it later on. The index is easily extracted with a math operation. Eg. `"10K"+0=10` in Awk.

Processing `file1` is done with the next line. Here we just check if the character matches for any of the entries in the associative array.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk and grep:

```
awk -v FPAT='[0-9]+|[A-Z]+' '{ print "^.{" $1-1 "}" $2 }' file1 | grep -Ef - file2
```

Output:

```
AETYUIOOILAKSJ
RYXURIAJSKDMAO
URITORIEJAHSJD
JAQIAUXCNCVUFO
```